# HTML/CSS - Changing properties of a text field

Tags: html, css, text, field, styling

Is it possible to change the properties of a text field when it's selected/active (i.e. being typed in). I'd like to simply change the border colour but I haven't found a thing about actually doing it.

I tried using :active but that only works when the mouse is pressed (obviously I guess)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the selector you want is called `:focus`

Answer (score 1):

To change the border of an input field when it's selected/active, use :focus

Example below:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="ageField" name="age" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#ageField:focus {
    border-color: #F00;
}
```

Explanation / Details
@ [W3Schools CSS:focus Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/sel_focus.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the onFocus/onBlur HTML elements.  With these you can use Javascript to modify the colors/style tags.

[onFocus/onBlur tutorial](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/_BODY_onFocus.html)